# Attach files to objects without using Salesforce storage

Tags: file-storage, data-storage

My company is looking to use Salesforce first as a CRM and then we are looking to re-implement ERP using the Force.com platform.

We would like the ability to attach files to individual objects, but have the objects stored outside of Salesforce so as to not count against our data cap.

Does anyone know of an app that allows you to do this?

Comment: There are tons of external services you can do with this. You may want to start with where your company would prefer to store the files, because your legal/compliance team may have its own requirements for where you can store company files.

Comment: n.b. there are ERP packages that run on SFDC, e.g. FinancialForce

Answer (score 0):

As a start I would read up on something like Dropbox. Depending on the amount of space a free account with them may be sufficient for what you're looking for, and they have a pretty decently documented API to work with as well.

Dropbox API: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs

As far as implementation in Visualforce I would steer clear of using the baked in apex:inputFile field types and fall back to HTML standard input fields. There are some limitations that you will run into such as the [viewstate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46576/inputfile-exceeds-maximum-viewstate-limit) being exceeded during standard operations.